# How can I get only the downloadable product URL in email template?

Tags: email-templates, downloadable, ce-1.9.1.0

As the title suggest and as screeshot show, how can I get only the downloadable product URL of every product ordered and show it in email template?

I want to highlight the link(s) in the email sent.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a block in a custom module that fetches download links from the database for current order. It is similar to how download links are currently generated for each order item. Block can be added to order emails using custom layout update handle, same way order items are added.

Module structure is pretty simple, we only need two files.
First one is our module configuration in `app/code/local/Custom/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custom_module>
                <class>Custom_Module_Block</class>
            </custom_module>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And our block: `app/code/local/Custom/Module/Block/Email/Download/Links.php`

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Email_Download_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_linksCollection;

    public function getDownloadLinksCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_linksCollection)) {
            $this->_linksCollection = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection();
            $this->_linksCollection->getSelect()->where('order_item_id IN (?)', $this->_getItemIds());
        }

        return $this->_linksCollection;
    }

    public function getPurchasedLinkUrl($item)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', array(
            'id'        => $item->getLinkHash(),
            '_store'    => $this->getOrder()->getStore(),
            '_secure'   => true,
            '_nosid'    => true
        ));
    }

    protected function _getItemIds()
    {
        $itemIds = array();

        foreach ($this->getOrder()->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $itemIds[] = $item->getId();
        }

        return $itemIds;
    }
}
```

Obviously we will also need a template file for our block and a layout update file to add our handle.

Template location is arbitrary, I saved it in `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/custommodule/email/download/links.phtml` and it looks like this:

```
<?php if ($this->getDownloadLinksCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-weight: 700; padding: 10px 15px; background: #f1f1f1; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left; font-size: 11px;" class="cell-name">
                <?php echo $this->__('Download Links') ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getDownloadLinksCollection() as $link): ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 6px 18px; margin: 0; width: 100%; background: #e1f0f8;">
                    <a style="color:#1E7EC8;" href="<?php echo $this->getPurchasedLinkUrl($link) ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($link->getLinkTitle()) ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif ?>
```

I didn't want to register new layout file so I opted for `local.xml` instead. File is saved in `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <email_download_links>
        <block type="custom_module/email_download_links" name="email.download.links" as="email.download.links" template="custommodule/email/download/links.phtml"/>
    </email_download_links>

</layout>
```

Now we just have to insert this in our email template and we are done. I did it from admin `(System > Transactional Emails)` since I already had order email configured there. You just have to find a suitable location, depending on your markup, and insert this piece of code:

`{{layout handle="email_download_links" order=$order}}`

Of course you can always change markup in `links.phtml` to fit your specific needs.

And that's all there is to it. Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to put the link of download inside product  name in email

You can an order item dowanload using below code:

```
$links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $ITemId);
```

Get list of download link from  item

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
 echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('download') .
  $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', 
  array('id' => $link->getLinkHash(), '_store' => $order()->getStore(), 
  '_secure' => true, '_nosid' => true));
}
```

In Generally order email

```
 item is render from block  file  that means phtml
```

**Suppose:** New order  item is render from here
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtempla/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

add Below code:

```
if($_item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=='downloadable'){
$links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $_item->getId());
foreach ($links as $link) {
 echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('download') .
  $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', 
  array('id' => $link->getLinkHash(), '_store' => $this->getItem()->getOrder()->getStore(), 
  '_secure' => true, '_nosid' => true));
}
}
```

Hope this will ........ help me